# python exception: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, exception, hash

```
 try:
    return [ True, errors[error], error ] # Error found
 except SoapFault as e: #or this could be Exception as e doesn't matter
    print str(e)
```

I'm getting

```
['soapenv', 'Sender', 'invalid request']
unhashable type: 'list'
```

what's wrong with that unhashable list, and when I'm trying to `print e[2]`, I'm getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: What is the context of this code? Are you doing anything with the list after it is returned?

Comment: Most likely "error" is a list and "errors[error]" is failing. Try putting that on a line by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you sure error is a number and not a String like '1', for example? Maybe that's a problem.
For the second answer, e is probably not an array. Just when its converted to String it may print the contents of a wrapped array.

Anyway, try to give more context to your question. Edit it to include a test that gives your error in a way that people can reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning a list to something that expects a hashable type, like an int, a string or a tuple of hashable types. That causes the message about `unhashable type: list`. Lists are unhashable because they are mutable; changing their contents would change their hashvalue, which is not allowed. A common way to get this error is to try and use a list as a key in a dict, or as an item in a set.

The second error, about `tuple index out of range`, means you tried to index a tuple beyond its end. It means that what you are trying to index is not this `['soapenv', 'Sender', 'invalid request']` list, but some other item. It could be a tuple *containing* that list, but without looking at that tuple, it's impossible to say. Try printing its `repr()`.